# Whitespace on last Container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn about responsive webdesign.

I have created three div Container side by side with a percentage width and a percentage margin. Every-time I run the code there is a little White-space on the last Container.

Is it possible to fix this?

```
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qK3Mj/) link.

I have the same Problem when i have 4 containers with 25% without margin. Every-time i resize the Browser there is a little White-Space on the right Container. Noticed that the problem is only in Safari. What should i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you use ".66" for dividing the values exactly 100% won't give proper results. Try to use 0.5% or 1%. I just update your CSS like below and it is working fine.

```
 .one
 {
width: 32.5%;
height: 200px;
background: #ECF0F1;
margin-right: 0.5%;
float: left;
 }
.two
 {
width: 33%;
height: 200px;
background: #ECF0F1;
margin-left: 0.5%;
margin-right: 0.5%;
float: left;
 }
 .three
 {
width: 32.5%;
height: 200px;
background: #ECF0F1;
margin-left: 0.5%;
float: left;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks first for your answer. I want every container with the same width and also the problem with the white-space is there when i change the browser size.